# Reflect.js, What is it?

Tags: javascript, parsing, angular

[Github](https://github.com/zaach/reflect.js) repo says:

Implementation of Mozilla's Parser API in JavaScript. There are few examples on github and mozilla's [reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API). I have seen this library being used in one of [Angular 2 seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) project as well.

But what is the use of this library? Can someone explain in easy words to elaborate purpose/advantage of this library.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/gdi2290/es7-reflect-metadata

Comment: @Nexus23 You're confusing Reflect.js (abandoned AST) with reflect-metadata (used by Angular2 ).

Answer (score 0):

It is literally just a javascript shell, much like node you can use it to write JS interactively in the shell or run JS files with it.

SpiderMonkey is Mozilla's JavaScript engine written in C/C++.

Parser, is a JS API version of that, you can use it to write tools that manipulate JS files, like a linter or compiler.

Reflect is a super old version of that which, as far as I know, is not a viable option given the other tools we have today. Note that the repo was last updated in 2012, and the JS is only ES3 compliant.